FT232H USB to I2C Device Not Detected
I am using an IC from FTDI, FT232H. I am using it to connect to a video decoder, via I2C, from a USB port on my type6 CPU module. I am able to detect the FT232H and install the proper driver on the IC that sets it as a USB to I2C bridge. However when I run my code as a master and scan I do not detect anything.
I decided to do some testing, and connected a module from Adafruit that uses the same FT232H IC to see if my code is correct, via my USB port on the carrier. The module has the exact same set up as the onboard FT232H device on my carrier, USB to I2C. I disabled the FT232H on my carrier so that my code only detected the Adafruit module, which it did. Again, when I ran my code no slave address got returned. After further troubleshooting, I disconnected my boot NVME, to see if there was a problem with my code or OS ( Linux Redhat). I connected the NVME drive to a computer, booted the OS, used the same code and connected the Adafruit FT232H module and it worked. My code returned the expected 0x50 address. Now that I know my OS and code is working I decided to test the type6 CPU module, to test the BIOS settings werent wrong. I removed it from my carrier board and connected it to a development carrier board from Congatec. I installed the NVME card to boot the OS, I connected the Adafruit FT232H module and ran my code. The I2C adress, 0x50 was returned, just what I was expecting. My last test, I wondered if my USB port on my carrier didn't have enough power, so I connected a Dell docking station that has an external power to it and connected the USB 3.0, to my carrier, same USB port I've been using. I ran everything again, the FT232 got detected by the CPU, I ran the code, but again, no returned address. I have used this USB port on my carrier to load software to the carrier, I used a USB hub, with multiple device like keyboards, mouse, and drives and it has worked properly. I am installing the same driver always, running the same code, and same Bios settings. Assuming my carrier layout, and power network delivery are good:
What can be causing this issue, that my carrier doesn't detect the I2C device on the Adafruit module nevertheless the one on my carrier?
The boot MVMe is connected via a PCIe switch that connects to my type6 cpu module. I am using 3.3V self powered configuration for the FT232H.

So how are the FT232 devices configured? One might have a setting to show VID:PID of VCP UART adapter and the other one to show that D2XX driver should be loaded. What does dmesg or lsusb say about the adapters?

+1 For some really good troubleshooting. Just by curiosity, what happens when you try scanning for 0xA0 instead of 0x50? I ask because some OEMs like Dell and HP bit shift their slave addresses.

@Colin our code scans address 00 to 11111111, so every possible address.

@Justme On both instances our code shows the message that the device is connected and binded to the correct driver. the command lsusb shows the device on my carrier and the Adafruit module.

Post your schematics. Also have you read the chip errata?
